# React app gets slow renders slow after emitting socketio message

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rendering

I have a react app. The code does work perfectly but after using it. It starts getting slow. After waiting for a while you can use it again.

When you press a button, I use socketio to emit a message.

**Function call takes longer after using it multiple times.**
[image]

The function call is part of `websocket.js`. However when you dig deeper in the functions it seems like react rendering is taking longer.

**Function that is taking a lot of time.**
[image]

So react takes a lot of time to render the view. I can only think then that I don't delete something which will use a lot of memory and thus slow down the rendering process. On the picture you see that it is in the file `react-dom.development.js`, the issue also occurs when it is build for production.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import Card from './Card.js'

class Game extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      socket: this.props.socket,
      card: {
        "name": "",
        "cardValues": {}
      }
    }
    this.props.socket.emit("startGame");
  }
  render() {
    let {socket, card} = this.state;
    socket.on("startGame", (data) => this.setState({
        card: data["card"],
    }))
    socket.on("nextCard", (data) => this.setState({
        card: data["nextCard"],
    }))
    return (
      <div className="Game">
          <p>GAME</p>
          <Card socket={socket} card={this.state.card}/>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Game;
```

This part uses the class `Card`.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Card extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      socket: this.props.socket,
    }
  }

  chooseCardValue = (value) => {
      this.state.socket.emit("chooseCard", {"cardValue": value});
  }

  render() {
    let card = this.props.card;
    return (
      <div className="Card">
          <h3 className="Country">{card["name"]}</h3>
          <ul>
            {
              Object.keys(card["cardValues"]).map((value, i) => {
                return <li key={i}><button onClick = {
                    this.chooseCardValue.bind(null, value)
                }>{value}: {card["cardValues"][value]}</button></li>
              })
            }
          </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Card;
```

It is here where the buttons are defined. When you click the button it triggers the function `chooseCardValue` which becomes slow after time.

Why does it become so slow, and what is the cause?

I tried to only include the parts that could be relevant. The whole classes are available here just in case: https://lpaste.net/3474101090415280128

Comment: Someone has given my question a downvote. I don't know why and I would really appreciate feedback, so I know what I can do to improve my question.

Comment: I don't why this question was downvoted, it's a very detailed question with great examples. I've been looking for this for a while, and your question led me to the answer. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are attaching your socket listeners inside the render method. This means that every time your app re-renders you will add 2 extra listeners. Additionally, inside the listeners you call `setState`, which triggers a re-render, which adds another listener.

The first time you get a message your app will render once, and add a listener.
The second time you get a message your app will render twice (once for each listener) and you will add 2 listeners.
The third time there will be 4 renders.
Then 8, 16, 32 and so on.

Essentially what you need to do is not add those listeners in the render method. You could try moving them to the `constructor` or the `componentDidMount` method, but really it should be somewhere external to the component tree.

For clarity these are the lines that I'm talking about:

```
let {socket, card} = this.state;
socket.on("startGame", (data) => this.setState({
    card: data["card"],
}))
socket.on("nextCard", (data) => this.setState({
    card: data["nextCard"],
}))
```

Comment: So all of the `socket.on` events should be in `componentDidMount` or in a different file away from the components? If you know any examples that do this I am happy to know.

Comment: Also: would this example here also be considered 'bad': https://github.com/vlw0052/React-Chat-App/blob/master/src/components/Layout.js Or why would it be oke to do it in this particular case?